# Python Adds One More Blank

Tags: python

```
data = 3

for i in range(1, data + 1):
    for j in range(1, data + 1):
        if j > (data - i):
            print("#", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")

        if j == data:
            print(" ", "#" * i, end="")

    print()
```

When I implement that code; even though I put one empty space under the `j == data` condition to have empty spaces there exist two blanks at the output. When I put two blanks it becomes three blanks at the middle.

I was expecting to have one empty space in the middle. The program gives one more empty spaces regardless of my space amount.

Comment: Re-read [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

Answer (score 2):

You have set the `end` argument for `print`. Try setting the `sep` argument to `''`. *Or* use f-strings.

```
data = 3

for i in range(1, data + 1):
    for j in range(1, data + 1):
        if j > (data - i):
            print('#', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
        if j == data:
            print(' ', '#' * i, sep='', end='')
    print()
```

With f-strings:

```
data = 3

for i in range(1, data + 1):
    for j in range(1, data + 1):
        if j > (data - i):
            print('#', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
        if j == data:
            print(f" {'#' * i}", end='')
    print()
```

But if you're using f-strings, you might as well also use `str.rjust` and `str.ljust`.

```
data = 3

for i in range(1, data + 1):
    x = '#' * i
    print(f"{x.rjust(data)} {x.ljust(data)}")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the print function prints every non-keyword argument separated by `sep`. By default `sep` is one single space.

So you could just replace the comma with a `+`:

```
data = 3
for i in range(1, data + 1):
    for j in range(1, data + 1):
        if j > (data - i):
            print("#", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
        if j == data:
            print(" "+ "#" * i, end="")
    print()
```

Or you set `sep` to `""`:

```
data = 3
for i in range(1, data + 1):
    for j in range(1, data + 1):
        if j > (data - i):
            print("#", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
        if j == data:
            print(" ", "#" * i, sep="", end="")
    print()
```